# CAPL program for receiving CAN FD message (64 bytes)

Tags: embedded, can-bus, capl

we are writing CAPL program for software update for CAN FD. we have configured Transfer Layer as well. but we are getting struggled to receive 64 bytes from CAN FD as the maximum data type in CAPL is qword (64 bits). is there any other thing to receive 64 bytes from CAN FD?please guide me if something is missing

this is 64 bit system and data type we tried is qword.

Comment: Why can't you use an array?

Comment: I haven't used this lib, but it either supports CAN FD or it doesn't. If it doesn't, you won't likely be able to maintain code compatibility if you try to modify it yourself.

Comment: As usual, please show what you have done so far and provide more details. Which data are you trying to access in CAPL? The raw (binary) data, the symbolic values, ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use a byte array which is the most suitable data type for storing bus data as DLC can be variable